# Fragment added from xml cannot be found in Backstack

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am adding a fragment in the xml file, but I was unable to find the instance of the fragment in the backstack.

Below is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragOneContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment class="com.myproject.fragments.fragmentname"
        android:id="@+id/frag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:tag="inspectionSearch">

    </fragment>
</FrameLayout>
```

Below is the code I used to get the list of the fragments

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragmentManager.getFragments();
        for(int i=0;i<fragmentList.size();i++){
            Log.d(TAG,"Fragment at "+i+" = "+fragmentList.get(i).getClass().getName());
        }
```

Note: The fragments I added dynamically in fragOneContainer was appearing in the backstack.

How do I get the instance of the fragment I added in the xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragments added from xml do not store in backstack. The main point is if you add the fragment through xml it is statically allocated, you cannot replace it. If you want backstack then add this fragment dynamically through the java (or kotlin)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I found when I fiddled around with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want fragment list only then you can get it with getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()
whether its dynamic or statically added from xml file like below:

> Use getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() as below:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragmentManager.getFragments();
for(int i=0;i<fragmentList.size();i++){
    Log.d(TAG,"Fragment at "+i+" = "+fragmentList.get(i).getClass().getName());
}
```

> instead of

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = InspectionSearchFrame.fm;
```

we can not get that fragment in backstack which is added in xml because we have to manually put that in backstack entry.
If you will use getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() then you will get 0 count 
because getSupportFragmentManager() will not count that fragments which are added in xml but it can still give you list with getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() method.

Comment: I did not get the fragment list like that, you have pasted essentially the same code I have put. I could not find statically added fragment that way. Thanks

Comment: ok i understand but you can get fragment list in this way and then in your onCreate() method of activity, try to put that fragment in backstack entry.

Comment: In that way you can get, but thats not the question. I had asked about getting the fragment added statically via xml.